# how to read a SAS data (.sas7bat) in R

Tags: r

```
install.packages('haven')
library(haven)
hsb1 <- read_sas("C:\\Users\\...\\hsb1.sas7bdat")
```

however, it does not work, please see the message below:

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘readr’

My question:
how to fix that?
BTW, no SAS installed in my PC, does this reason cause the error?

Comment: Install the package `readr`.

Comment: Always install dependent packages, too, with `install.packages(..., dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: `rxImport` from `RevoScaleR` can read both compressed and uncompressed SAS files.

Comment: works， thanks a lot!